# is it possible to run node.js in such a way that emulates ES5-only behaviour?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to make node.js throw an error for anything that requires ES6 without reinstalling a very old version?
That is: I have code for ES5 only browsers, which throws an error when it comes accross anything ES6 related. Is it possible to make node.js run in such a way that the results will be the same? (as in it will also throw errors)

Comment: I assume you want to use the latest Node version?

Comment: yes, if possible. added clarification

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a linter on your code, like ESLint, and this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-es5

When incorporated into your build/deploy process, the linter will error on the ES5 code you want to catch! This is more of a coding rule than an execution rule, as the version of node, if ES6 enabled, will always recognize the ES6 syntax. It will work with ES5 syntax too, so using a Linter will prevent ES6 from getting deployed. Many editors these days have tools to show linting while typing/saving as well.